# how to display card horizotally inline

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

hope you all are doing well
I am making dynamic cards but it is not showing inline, i would like to make it inline with scroll bar

[image]

i would like to make it horizontal inline

```
<div className='scrollmenu d-inline'>
                {
                    data.map((user, index) => (
                        <div >
                            <div className="card text-center" style={{ width: 10 + 'rem' }}>
                                <img className='m-auto mt-2' src={user.img} alt="Avatar" style={{ width: 100 + 'px' }} />
                                <a href="#home">{user.name}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
```

here is the css

```
div.scrollmenu {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  div.scrollmenu a {
    display: inline-block;
 
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  div.scrollmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #777;
  }



  img {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please add

```
.scrollmenu {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox_container.asp

Comment: add more information to this answer

Comment: I love flexboxes (and grids). they are making a row or a grid very easy and without any complexity. When I'm using flex box I always check the guide from css-tricks: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score -1):

First: Remove parent div from div.card,
Then apply this css in div.card ->

```
div.card {
 width: 300px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Maybe he don't want to set a fixed width.... better use flex or grid in this case

Comment: After @UPinar answer, This is alternative way. And same way he need to work.

Comment: @Sfili_81 my main motto here is to tell them to remove parent div from card. Even if they will use flexbox, they have to remove that parent div. Main problem he is getting problem because of parent div.